# Can't use all cores in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I was trying to make a parallel loop, but I've found R can't utilize all my 8 cores, it uses only 1 with this code:

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = no_cores)

sum.of.squares <- foreach(i = 1:10e4, .combine = "+", .init = 0) %dopar% {
  sqrt(i)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

It uses only about 13-15% of CPU. Why?

Using Windows 8.1 with R 3.2.1.

Comment: what does no_cores return?

Comment: @ddiez 7. There is minus one core for me.

Comment: Plain vanilla R isn't very good at parallelization. Revolution R's version uses all cores *and* MMX CPU commands to achieve 7x speed increase on a quad-core i7 for `svd`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos maybe you are right that plain R is not very good at parallelization. But the OP's example should work. I can reproduce the behavior in my laptop, using both the cluster and multicore interfaces in doParallel. To the OP, have you tried using the `parallel` package directly? (maybe by using `mclapply`- this works for me)

Comment: @m0nhawk, sorry. In my previous comment I suggested using `mclapply`. But now I realized you are on windows, which prevents you to use that approach. Maybe then use `parLapply`, although not so familiar with it since I always work on *nix-like environments.

Comment: @ddiez Looks like R for Windows have some parallel limitations. I have achieved some performance increase, but for this kind of simple calculation it's too low (around 2-3 times only). Looks like for parallel stuff I'll still use C++.

Comment: Looping is always expensive and a good way to prevent vectorization (or parallelization). Using `x<-1:10e4;  y<-sqrt(x);  sum(y)` takes much less than a second so wouldn't benefit at all by multi-process parallelization

Comment: @m0nhawk not really - the code you used parallelizes very badly. Single threaded R can execute this a lot faster. Remember, R isn't a compiled language and a loop costs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know, thus I was comparing to `s<-c(); for(i in 1:1e5) s<-cbind(s, sqrt(i)); sum(s)`.

Comment: Compare it to `sum(sqrt(1:10e4))`. Horrible R, but instantaneous response

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, for that particular example it does not make sense to use this code. The OP code is basically the same as used at the beginning in the `doParallel` vignette, where what you said is mentioned. Basically, is a dummy example to check that everything works fine. It seem it does not work fine.

Comment: Give the cores something to do and you should see some load. In your example overhead dominates everything. Parallelization is for code that can't be improved (using reasonable programming resources) and is still slow. I.e., not for calculating square roots in R.

Comment: Obviously it's because you told R that you have *no_cores*.  You're lucky it's even using one when you told it that you have none! \s

Comment: And regarding the code you are comparing to: [Circle 2](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use R Revolution Open (RRO) 3.2

http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/rro/installation/

It comes integrated with the [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) parallel math libraries.

See a [fuller comparison here](http://serbantanasa.com/2015/06/12/r-vs-revolution-r-open-3-2-0/).

Comment: I'll give it a try, though it "crashes" the RStudio (and I'm in no want to find new IDE).

Comment: I use it w/ RStudio w/ no problems.

Comment: RStudio allows you to select the R distribution you want from Options/General. I've switched mine to RRO's and have no issues. Far better than RRO's. As for the MKL - it's the SSE/AVX commands *and* the optimized algorithms that minimize floating point errors. Multiplying two 3x3 matrices with a single CPU command is nice. And the memory management when processing a large data set as a stream (eg decoding)

Comment: It's just when I run RStudio with RRO - it's the white screen only. Looks like I have issues with RStudio installation.